# Can I use two viewmodel for one fragment?

Tags: android, viewmodel

I am using MVVM in my Android project. I have Create and Edit fragments. This 2 fragments have largely the same function. If I write functions which they have the same function in a common view model, Can I use the common viewmodel with own viewmodel of fragments. For example Can I use like below;

```
 CommonViewModel(){

  void selectPriority()
      .
      .
      .
   otherthings...}
```

---

```
 CreateViewModel(){

  LiveData<CommonViewModel> cvm;
      .
      .
      .
   otherthings...}
```

---

```
  EditViewModel(){

    LiveData<CommonViewModel> cvm;
        .
       .
       .
     otherthings...}
```

Instead of this

```
 CreateViewModel(){

  void selectPriority()
      .
      .
      .
   otherthings...}
```

---

```
  EditViewModel(){

    void selectPriority()
        .
       .
       .
     otherthings...}
```

Or can you suggest to me different way which I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through Inheritance,Make a common view model and extend it in edit and creat view model, like

```
class CreatEditViewModel{

public void selectPriority(){
  //to something....
}
public void other(){
  //to something....
}
```

}

```
class CreateViewModel extends CreatEditViewModel{
```

}

```
class EditViewModel extends CreatEditViewModel{
```

}

You can not put these logic in BaseViewModel because BaseViewModel is extended by all ViewModel.

Comment: Yes I guess, this approach more well.

Answer (score 1):

You can with the help of Inheritance,  create a base class and put all the common functionality there, then create two more classes which inherit the base class. this way you can achieve what you want.

e.g.

```
class BaseViewModel{

    public void selectPriority(){

    }
    public void other(){

    }
}

class CreateViewModel extends BaseViewModel{

}

class EditViewModel extends BaseViewModel{

}
```

With the above example, CreateViewModel and EditViewModel both inherit BaseViewModel hence they have access to all the functions of BaseViewModel class. All the common methods will be available wit BaseViewModel. The methods you would create in CreateViewModel and EditViewModel will not be visible to each other.

Comment: I am already using BaseViewModel but even so this approach helped me. I have created CreateEditBaseViewModel class and I write all functions which they use common in common BaseViewModel . Thank you :)